# How to know the webpage is using dynamic id

Tags: selenium, automated-tests

For test automation, how can we know if the webpage is using a dynamic id. Here, I don't mean *how can we get the dynamic id*. Instead, I want to know how to use API, e.g. Selenium API, to know if the web element is using dynamic id.

For example, some ComboBox's id will not change when we select its *option*. But for other ComboBox's id, it may change as selecting its *option*.

So, do we have a way to detect, or to know, if the web element in the webpage is using a dynamic id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately you have no way to discover if and `id` will change using Selenium.

The only way an HTML element could have its `id` attribute changed is through JavaScript code. And the only way to know if a piece of JavaScript code changes an `id` is to execute it. (In other words, you can't, ahead of time, know the `id` will change. You can only know that JS code changes an `id` when it actually changes the `id`, and by this time, of course, the changing already happened.)

If, on the other hand, you want to know if an element had its `id` changed, you can, before the change takes place, get a hold of it through Selenium (using `driver.findElement()`) and then keep checking if its attribute changed. (If the `WebElement` instance becomes stale in the process, you could, as a workaround, add a class with a unique name to it, and then find it back using `by.className()` - since you may not find it again by its `id` like before, as it could have changed.)